Why is argc[argv - 1] equivalent to argv[argc - 1]?
I was reviewing some old code from my piscine at school 42.
While reviewing, we found this file containing a put string function and a main function:
I inversed argc and argv in the main function.
#include <unistd.h>

void    putstr(char *str)
{
    int x;

    x = 0;

    while (str[x])
        x++;
    write(1, str, x);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 0)
        write(1, "\n", 1);
    else
    {
        putstr(argc[argv - 1]);
        putstr("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}

I tried compiling as is with CC using the flags -Wall -Wextra -Werror and with the arguments aa aa aa bb bb bb cc cc cc 123 puts 123 to standard out. It seems to output the last argument.
I have genuinely got no clue as to why. I have asked three of my friends and they couldn't find an answer. How can it even compile with the flags as putstr takes a char * and here we're passing an integer?

ptr[index] is equivalent to *(ptr + index) which is equivalent to *(index + ptr) which is equivalent to index[ptr]. The [] notation is a syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic.

In C things get weird as x[2] and 2[x] end up being the same thing.

Consider an ordinary array element reference, E1[E2] where E1 is an array. C 2018 6.5.2.1 specifies array subscripting, and paragraph 2 says:

… The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).

That is:

Removing the parentheses we do not need in this case, that is *(E1+E2).
In this, E1 is an array. It is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.
Adding E2 produces a pointer that points E2 elements beyond that, so it points to element E2 of the array E1.
Applying * produces the element from that pointer.

Now consider what happens if you reverse this:

E2[E1] is, by definition, *(E2+E1).
E1 is converted to a pointer to its first element.
Adding E2 produces a pointer that points E2 elements beyond that.
Applying * produces the element from that pointer.

In other words, because + operation is the same if its operands are switched, the [] operation is the same if its operands are switched.
Now consider argc[argv - 1]. This is a bit different because we did not switch the operands argv and argc - 1 but only switched parts of them, argv and argc.
In the original, argv[argc - 1] is element argc - 1 of the argv array.
In argc[argv - 1], argv - 1 subtracts 1 from the pointer argv. Technically, this is not defined by the C standard if argv points to the first element of an array, because pointer arithmetic is not defined if you move before the start of an object. However, the compiler does not have any visibility about what was passed to it beyond the address, so it must work with the address it was given. In a C implementation with a flat address space, argv - 1 must produce a pointer to one element before where argv points.
Then argc[argv - 1] is *(argc + (argv - 1)). The addition produces a pointer to argc elements beyond where argv - 1 points, which is argc - 1 elements beyond where argv points, so it is, given the caveat above, the same as argv + (argc - 1).
Then applying * produces that element.

I see a few points here where you may be misunderstanding the code

putstr(argc[argv - 1]);

Here we pass the last command line argument to the putstr function
argc[argv - 1] is the same as argv[argc - 1], because [] is just a sugar for pointer arithmetic as Eugene pointed in the comments. So we just take the last argument (argc - 1), from argv array and pass it to the function

while (str[x]) x++;

Here you simply counts a symbols in the str string. Iterate through the characters in str, until the current character (str[x]) points to NULL or '\0'

write(1, str, x);

Write first x characters from the string str to 1-st file descriptor. There are a list of default file descriptors:
stdin - 0
stdout - 1
stderr - 2
So in this line, we just writes string to stdout
